# For row reduced echelon matrix for a homogeneous system of equations, what solution would be there for r=n and r>n

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, homogeneous-equation

I was learning Linear Algebra from Hoffman and Kunze. There the authors prove that for a row reduced echelon matrix with rows r and columns n for a homogeneous system of equations X, if r < n, X has a non-trivial solution, which I understood (substituting, r unknowns with remaining unknowns). However, what would happen in case of

1. r = n
2. r > n

For r = n, I am guessing it would be trivial solution only as no substitution is possible. Please correct me if wrong.

Comment: Well, just think how many unknowns are remaining to "substitute"?

Comment: What is rank of the matrix?Is it r or less than than r?

Comment: @ASHWINISANKHE It's r. I can't seem to correct my question. It should be like : reduced echelon matrix with with non-zero rows r. Sorry for the omission.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I believe it should be zero for both case 1. and 2. So I think trivial solutions in case 2 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ax=0$ is homogeneous system.It always have trivial solution.If r=n then system will have trivial solution.As $rank(A)\le min{(r,n)}$. Hence r can not be greater than n.

Comment: Thanks. I have not yet formally gone through the rank concept. But a quick search showed your assumption is true ( rank(A)≤min(r,n) ) . So both case 1 and 2 would have only trivial solutions. I guess I would have much better understanding once I go through the proof for rank(A)≤min(r,n)